# how to check if the ddl.selectedindexchange event has been fired on the page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, panels

here is my code : on page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //On first request
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        panel1.Visible = true;
        panel2.Visible = false;
        panel3.Visible = false;
    }
    //for subsequent postbacks
    else 
    {
        //If the enquiry is direct
        if ( Direct_Rdbtn.Checked)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = false;
            panel3.Visible = true;

            //add default text value "D" for date dropdownlist of DOB
            if (DOB_Date_Ddl.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                ListItem li = new ListItem();
                li.Text = "D";
                DOB_Date_Ddl.Items.Add(li);
            }
        }
        //For all other sources of enquiries
        else 
        { 
     //in this if statement i actualy want to check for `selectedindexchange` event togther with `AllOthers_Rdbtn.Checked`
            if (AllOthers_Rdbtn.Checked )
            {
                panel1.Visible = false;
                panel2.Visible = false;
                panel3.Visible = true;

            }
            else if (AllOthers_Rdbtn.Checked)
            {
                panel1.Visible = false;
                panel2.Visible = true;
                panel3.Visible = false;
                LinkButton1.Enabled = false;
                LinkButton1.Text = "";
                en.mainEnq_Stu_Mobile = TextBox1.Text;

            }

        }

    }       
}
```

[image]
now the thing is that there are three panels on my page the visibility of those have been played around. On panel one there are two radio buttons which decides the vsibility of two panel 2nd and third namely. the first panel is displayed on the first page request. the problem is i have dropdownlist control with auto post back turned on in the third panel . as soon as  there is a post back due to ddl and the page load event fires and at that time

> AllOthers_Rdbtn.Checked is also checked so instead of the third panel being displayed. panel2 gets displayed again. 
>   what i want is a way to check if the selectedindexchange event has fired togther with the Direct_Rdbtn.checked in the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move code to event handler:

```
protected void Direct_Rdbtn_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //If the enquiry is direct
    if (Direct_Rdbtn.Checked)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!it works perfect. how stupid of me not to think of this lol :D